# Google Script to create filters that hide newly added values. (sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, view, hidden-field

I am viewing data that comes from google forms in google sheets. I want to create filter views, in google sheet, to display only blank values in a column. The problem is that when a new value is inputted in google sheet, the filter view automatically adds this value in the filter, and I need to manually adjust the filter again.

To resolve this, I tried to create a script, that I would link to a button. The idea behind the script is to first get all the values in my column, and then setting those values in a hide function.

Right now, the script is showing all values:

```
function applyCustomFilter() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1'); 
  
  // Create a filter if it doesn't exist
  var filter = sheet.getFilter() || sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).createFilter();
  

  // Get all the values in Column M (column index 13)
  var valuesColumnM = sheet.getRange("M2:M" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  // Determine the hidden values for Column M based on the data
  var hiddenValuesColumnM = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < valuesColumnM.length; i++) {
    if (valuesColumnM[i][0] !== 'DATES' && valuesColumnM[i][0] !== '') {
      hiddenValuesColumnM.push(valuesColumnM[i][0]);
    }
  }

  // Define the filter criteria for column M (column index 13) with dynamically determined hidden values
  var criteriaColumnM = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setHiddenValues(hiddenValuesColumnM) // Show 'DATES' and blanks in column M
    .build();

  // Apply the filter criteria to the respective columns
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(13, criteriaColumnM);
}
```

I am expecting the filter to hide all values and display only blanks (plus my the tittle of my table ("ValueA, ValueB").

Any ideas?

Comment: About `I want to create filter views` and your showing script, in your showing script, it seems that the basic filter is used. But, in your question, it seems that you are using the filter view. Those are different filters. Which do you want to use in your actual situation? And about `I am expecting the filter to hide all values and display only blanks (plus my the tittle of my table ("ValueA, ValueB")`, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, here's and example [link (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zml9R70BmMHuD-3ngpqpz20JMYYCMWGxKVH8ewOkSj4/edit?usp=sharing).

Basic Filter or Filter views would work. I can use on or the other. 
Like I tried to show in my example, the problem is that row values will change in time. And when there's a new value added, it is added to the filter. In my example "Row Added", the filter would include the added value, but I want to exclude it. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, how about modifying `var valuesColumnM = sheet.getRange("M2:M" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();` to `var valuesColumnM = sheet.getRange("M2:M" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();` in your showing script? When the date value is filtered by the basic filter, the cell value is required to be used. But, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result. So, I post it as a comment. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function applyCustomFilter() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var filter = sh.getFilter() || sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).createFilter();
  var vsm = sh.getRange("M2:M" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var hvsm = vsm.filter(v => v);//filters out the ones that are truthy
  var crm = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(hvsm).build();
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(13, crm);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper,  I may have missed something, it only filter out the tittle of my table. I want to remove all values except the blanks and the tittle.
See example here [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SORzF0xzPn66UkAHgMcaElZWO_QQk8KKq08NifRu0GM/edit?usp=sharing)
In other words, is there a way to remove all the date values only?

Comment: Sorry but I do not follow links to other's spreadsheets because it reveals my email.